# Remove duplicate characters in bash

Tags: text-processing, command-line

If I am having a line as:

```
There are seven pencil
```

I want to print this as:

```
Ther a svn pcil
```

What is the bash shell command for this?

*Clarification: the goal is to remove all, at least twice occuring letters, except their first occurence.*

Comment: FYI - bash is just your shell; it has some powerful features, but mainly it's for calling other utilities, such as text processors, etc.

Comment: What is the rule that translates the input to the output?

Comment: Why is the space repeated in the output?  Which other characters can be repeated?

Answer (score 11):

Based on sed classic synthax `s/replace-this/with-that/g` where `g` means global replace = all occurences , someone can use `2g` instead of `g` which means `global replacement but after second occurence` (this is a `gnu sed` extension).

Example that removes only `e`:

```
$ echo $a
there are seven pencil

$ echo $a | sed 's/e//2g'
ther ar svn pncil
```

To remove all duplicate letter we can make a trick like this:

```
$ sed -f <(printf 's/%s//2g\n' {a..z}) <<<"$a"
ther a svn pcil
```

Unfortunatelly this will not work : `sed 's/[a-z]//2g'`

The above trick uses process substitution `<( )` which can be used as file.

In my solution process substitution is treated like a `sed` script file, fed to `sed` by `-f` option = read sed commands from a file.

Comment: You don't need process substitution here. `sed "$(printf ...)"` will work just the same. You don't need `zsh`'s (or compatible) `<<<` operator either. Using `printf '%s\n' "$a" | sed...` would work with any shell.

Answer (score 6):

**`Awk`** solution (for case-sensitive cases):

```
s="There are seven pencil"
printf '%s\n' "$s" | awk -v FS="" '{ 
           for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
               if ($i==" " || !a[$i]++) printf "%s", $i; print "" 
       }'
```

- `-v FS=""` - set "empty" field separator so that each character becomes a separate field (not POSIX but a GNU extension supported by quite a few implementations)
- `for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)` - iterating over characters
- `if ($i==" " || !a[$i]++)` - if it's space char or having the 1st occurrence of a certain char

---

The output:

```
Ther a svn pcil
```

For case-insensitive, replace `a[$i]` with `a[tolower($i)]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's Bash itself.

```
s="There are seven pencil"
declare -A A
while IFS= read -rn1 a; do
 [ -z "$a" ] || [ -n "${A[$a]}" ] && continue
 printf %s "$a"
 [ "$a" == " " ] || A[$a]=x
done <<<"$s"
echo
```

Explanation line by line:

1. Assign the string to a variable

   ```
   s="There are seven pencil"
   ```
2. Declare an associative array `A`

   ```
   declare -A A
   ```
3. This one's a bit complex. But without details, it reads the string by single characters and assigns the character just read to `a`. It's a `while` loop.

   ```
   while IFS= read -rn1 a; do
   ```
4. Continue the loop (go to the next iteration, so read the next character) if the current character is empty (`[ -z "$a" ]`) or (`||`) if the value associated with this key (this character) has already been set (if it has then here it comes again, so we continue without printing it).

   ```
   [ -z "$a" ] || [ -n "${A[$a]}" ] && continue
   ```
5. Print the current character.

   ```
   printf %s "$a"
   ```
6. If the character is space - then don't execute `A[$a]=x` - that's what `||` means here. `A[$a]=x` is the association operation. To prevent all spaces no value should be assign to the key space in the `A` array. (See point 4.)

   ```
   [ "$a" == " " ] || A[$a]=x
   ```
7. This ends the `while` loop. `<<<"$s"` is a here-string redirection. It feeds the loop with the string.

   ```
   done <<<"$s"
   ```
8. This last `echo` prints the line separator. `printf` in point 5. printed only the character. Without this `echo` the output would appear on the same line as the following shell prompt. Remove it and see yourself.

   ```
   echo
   ```

Comment: I am struggling to figure this out. Would it be ok to have it explained a bit? I was wondering about it on your question about it.

Comment: @Guy Take a look now. As for my question, the code there is slightly different. Otherwise there would be no question. Compare line 6.

Comment: Cheers, that definitely makes a bit more sense!

Answer (score 2):

**`Python`** solution:

`remove_dups.py` script:

```
import sys

s, res = set(), []
for c in sys.argv[1]:    # iterating over characters
    if c not in s:       # on the 1st occurrence of a character
        res.append(c)
        if not c.isspace(): s.add(c)
print(''.join(res))      # print unique chars
```

---

Usage:

```
s="There are seven pencil"
python remove_dups.py "$s"
```

The output:

```
Ther a svn pcil
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed` solution:

- for single alphabetic character:

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'here hear' | sed 's/\(\([[:alpha:]]\).*\)\2/\1'
  here ear
  ```
- for all of them, the `g` flag won't help as characters already processed won't be checked again. So, use a loop - 't' will branch to the label as long as substitution succeeds

  ```bsh
  $ echo There are seven pencils | sed -e :a -e 's/\(\([[:alpha:]]\).*\)\2/\1/; ta'
  Ther a svn pcil
  ```

  With GNU `sed`, you could shorten it to:

  ```bsh
  sed -E ':a;s/(([[:alpha:]]).*)\2/\1;ta'
  ```

to ignore case (still with GNU `sed`):

```bsh
$ echo 'There this That' | sed -E ':a; s/(([[:alpha:]]).*)\2/\1/i; ta'
Ther is a
```

with `perl` (here limited to ASCII letters only):

```bsh
$ echo 'There are seven pencil' | perl -pe 'while(s/([a-zA-Z]).*?\K\1//g){}'
Ther a svn pcil
$ echo 'There this That' | perl -pe 'while(s/([a-z]).*?\K\1//gi){}'
Ther is a
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all duplicate characters (keeping only the first occurrence), in `zsh`:

```
$ s="There are seven pencils"
$ printf '%s\n' ${(j::)${(s::u)s}}
Ther asvnpcil
```

That approach can't be used if you want to exclude some characters from that de-duplication (like the space character in your example).

- `s::` split on the empty string to split the string into its character constituents [as some `awk` implementations do with an empty `FS`](/q/417105)
- `u`: unique: remove duplicates in the resulting array
- `j::`: join the elements of the array with empty strings in between.

Answer (score 0):

## An `awk` solution

Contents of input file `file.txt`:

```
There are seven pencil
```

For each line of `file.txt`, create a new string.  Place characters from the original line into the new string, one character at a time, if they have not already occurred on that line.  Always include space characters.  Print the new string when the entire line has been processed:

```
awk '{
       printme="" ;
       for ( n=1 ; n<=length($0) ; n++ ) {
         char=substr($0,n,1) ;
         if ( printme !~ char || char == " " ) printme = printme char ;
       } ;
       print printme ;
     }' "file.txt"
```

Output:

```
Ther a svn pcil
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by below simple sed command with for loop

input.txt

```
There are seven pencil
```

command:

```
 for i in {a..z}; do sed -i "s/$i//2g" input.txt; done
```

output

```
Ther a svn pcil
```

Comment: This is the same principle as [George Vasiliou’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419464/80216#419470), but a worse implementation.  George’s answer handles arbitrary standard input and standard output.  Your answer requires that the text be in a file, and then it reads and writes that file *26 times!!*